# Ruby ActionView FormBuilder radio button to set multiple values?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, activerecord, formbuilder

I am using FormBuilder in a Rails website to create a new ActiveRecord object.

I have two mutually-exclusive class fields, though, and I want to create a radio_button that allows me to choose which one to pick; however, the FormBuilder class seems to limit you to only setting one variable at a time per radio button set.

Is there a way to add in some secondary logic, whereby if one option is selected, the other attribute is automatically set, as well?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes. Create a new method on your model that accepts a value and sets the mutually exclusive fields based on its input, and another that will inspect the two fields and return a matching value for the form.

For instance, say you had a User model that can be a 'provider', or a 'customer', but not both. You could set the following methods:

```
def role=(str)
   if str == 'provider'
     self.provider = true
   elsif str == 'customer'
     self.customer = true
   end
end

def role
 if self.provider?
   'provider'
 elsif self.customer?
   'customer'
 else
   nil
 end
end
```

Then in your view, have your radio button reference 'role' rather than 'customer' or 'provider'.

```
<% form_for @user do |f| %>
  <%= f.radio_button :role, 'provider' %>
  <%= f.radio_button :role, 'customer' %>
<% end %>
```

Essentially what this will do is put the value of the checked button into the 'role' key of your params upon form submission, which in turn causse the value of the checked radio button to be sent to the `role=` method defined above when you do `User.create(params)` or `User.update(params)` in your controller. It will also run `@user.role` when building the form to see if a value is set already, and check the appropriate button. Don't forget to add the name of your new method to the permitted params for the appropriate controller as well.

Comment: Thanks, this worked! I wasn't able to get my 'role=' function (to continue this example) to be accessible by the form from other classes; however, I worked around that by dealing with it with the controller's params. Not entirely positive why it didn't work, though

Comment: @user3594939 I'm not sure exactly what you mean by 'accessible by the form from other classes'. Are you trying to call `f.radio_button :role` in a `form_for` call where the object passed to `form_for` is not a User? (to follow my example code)

Comment: Apologies; when I try to call role= from my controller, it says that it's an undefined method. I can use the getter, though